# POST variable always stays empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

This is the method in which i manage the data send with jquery.ajax. By default is send an empty string and on each change i watch the change on the input and resend it. Through console things are good but in php `$this->searchField` always has the value of an empty string

```
function checkInfo(){
        if(isset($_POST['searchField'])){
            $this->searchField = json_decode($_POST['searchField']);

                if ($this->searchField != ""){
                    $this->query = "SELECT * FROM myguests WHERE firstName like '%".$searchField."%'";
                }
                else if ($this->searchField == "") {
                    $this->query = "SELECT * FROM myguests ORDER BY id";
                }
                $this->tableDisplay();
                exit();
            }
            else{
                return "error";
            }
        }
```

This is my jquery ajax function :

```
function searchGuests(users){
  var data = {
    "searchField": users
  };
  console.log(data);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "text",
      url: "controllers/manageTable.php",
      data: data
    })
    .done(function(tr) {
      $("#tableBody").empty();
      $("#tableBody").append(tr);
    })
    .fail(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: what does the users variable holding?

Comment: You aren't sending any JSON so no need to use json_decode()

Answer (score -1):

Try encoding the users to a string before sending it over.

```
function searchGuests(users){
  var data = {
    "searchField": JSON.stringify(users);
  };
  console.log(data);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "text",
      url: "controllers/manageTable.php",
      data: data
    })
    .done(function(tr) {
      $("#tableBody").empty();
      $("#tableBody").append(tr);
    })
    .fail(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: No such method as `JSON.encode()` and the idea doesn't make sense either. jQuery uses `$.param()` to serialize objects by default

Comment: I solved it indeed it didn't needed to be json_decode -ed

Comment: confused it with php json_encode. it is JSON.stringify

Comment: please share your answer. Thanks